# Rails dalli gem, load session with session id

Tags: session, load, ruby-on-rails-3

is there a way to get the session info if i know the session id when dalli_store is used as the session store???r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into config/initializers/session_store.rb add

```
mem_options = {
  :key         => '_your_session_key',
  :secret      =>  ....
}

ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.insert_before(ActionController::Base.session_store, CMS::FlashSessionCookieMiddleware, mem_options[:key])
```

And your flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb should contain:

```
require 'rack/utils'

  module CMS

  class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
    def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
      @app = app
      @session_key = session_key
    end

    def call(env)
      if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
        params = ::Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
        env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [@session_key, params[@session_key]].join('=').freeze unless params[@session_key].nil?
      end
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

end
```